# How can I add redis.config to an Azure worker role?

Tags: azure, redis

Might be a bit of a silly question but here goes.

I want to run redis from an Azure worker role. As I need specific code to run after the redis server is started, I decided against using a ProgramEntryPoint entry in the csdef file, preferring to simply call Process.Start("redis-server") from within OnStart in my roles EntryPoint class.

Works fine.

I then added a redis.conf file (Build-Action set to None and CopyAlways set to true), the same way I added the redis-server.exe executable.

But no matter what I try, redis starts up and claims there is no config file specified.

Any clues?

---

So some more details, I'm using the 64 bit build of redis-server from here https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads. The server starts up fine provided I don't pass **redis.conf** to the command line.

Comment: The configuration file should be provided as a parameter of the redis-server command. It is not enough to create a file in the same directory. You need to find a way to launch a command line (executable with parameters).

Comment: Example of launching an executable with parameters here: http://blog.ntotten.com/2011/08/24/nodejs-on-windows-azure/

Comment: Ahh, I think I see what the problem is here. I had tried your solution previously (I found that same blog link a few hours ago) But I suspect it didn't work because I was using an older build of redis-server.exe. Let me give that a shot and report back. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I can report that no, this doesn't work for me. I'm using version 2.4.5 of redis-server from here https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads

Comment: Would you believe the issue was a misformed redis.conf file? But when I say misformed I mean I created it using Visual Studio by adding a new text file and changing it's extension to .conf. When I recreated it from notepad on a whim, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you believe the issue was a misformed redis.conf file? But when I say misformed I mean I created it using Visual Studio by adding a new text file and changing it's extension to .conf. When I recreated it from notepad on a whim, it worked!